# Uploading a photo to Instagram gives error

Tags: c#, json, instagram-api

Using `InstaSharper` SDK, I'm getting a `json` error doing a simple upload of a photo. I can authenticate and gather user info through the api. Also tried a few different ways of setting the URI on that InstaImage object to no avail.

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.

```
    public async Task CreatePost()
    {
        try
        {
            var img = new InstaImage()
            {
                URI = new Uri(Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\dev\testimg.jpg"), UriKind.Absolute).LocalPath,
                Height = 1050,
                Width = 700
            };

            // Errors below on postRequest: 
            // Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.
            var postRequest = await api.UploadPhotoAsync(img, "testing app");

            if (!postRequest.Succeeded)
                throw new InstagramPostException(postRequest.Info.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InstagramFollowException(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @JohnPete22 it's in the code block -- `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value...`